# Can't import Pyperclip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, pyperclip

I am having trouble importing Pyperclip in IDLE.
I am running windows 7 (64-bit).
I have Python 3.5.2 Installed on: C:\Python\Python35.
I opened command prompt and initiated the install by typing pip install pyperclip after changing directory to C:\Python\Python35\Scripts. 
It successfully installed Pyperclip-1.5.27. 
I then went to IDLE and typed in import pyperclip but the following error is showing up:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import pyperclip
ImportError: No module named 'pyperclip'

I tried to fix this by adding "C:\Python\Python35" to the end of the "Path" variable, in the systems environmental variables.

Comment: Did you run the setup.py file? Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081317/using-pyclips-and-import-clips-as-a-python-module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It unpacked pyperclip in the wrong directory. I copied the entire pyperclip folder and put it in C:/python/python35, now it works as it should. Seems like a noob mistake on my part, but it took me a long time to figure this out.  I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
pip3 install pyperclip
```

That installs pyperclip in python3.

Comment: Well, I've tried with "pip install pyperclip" your solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those working in a `venv`, make sure that you have `pyperclip` installed in the directory that your venv is running in. 
Eg. `C:\MY_PROJECT\venv\Lib\site-packages` should include the pyperclip module. If you don't find it here, have a look at where you installed Python and you'll find it there. 
Eg. `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages`