# Why is pyperclip "not found", even though it is clearly installed?

Tags: python, pyperclip

I'm doing a basic coding project for class.  It's the password locker from "Automate the Boring Stuff".

I have everything coded properly, compiled without errors and I've made the bat file and it's in the right spot.

This is the code (minus the dashes in front of the hashtags)

```
#! python3

#pw.py This is an insecure Password Locker.

PASSWORDS = {'yahooEmail':'12345', 'googleEmail':'23456','facebook':'34567', 'luggage':'45678'}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: py pw.py [account] - copy account password')
sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]   # first command line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[acount])
    print('Password for ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account +'.')
```

So it should, of course, just allow me to type in the key to see the value, and copy/past new values as needed.

But when I run it I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\shawn\Desktop\Python homework\pw.py", line 6, in <module>

    import sys, pyperclip

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

Comment: what do you mean it's `clearly installed`? how did you figure that out?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: Seems like a path problem. The instance of the interpreter which is running the code needs to be using a search path which contains the module. I have had this sort of problem when e.g. installing something through Anaconda and then trying to run code which uses it through IDLE

Comment: How did you install pyperclip?

Comment: You can see which modules are installed by typing `pip list` at a command prompt (or maybe `pip3 list`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't import Pyperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111340/cant-import-pyperclip)